# Symfony 3 - listener on LoginAction - kernelException

Tags: php, symfony

### Description:

I would like to use a Listener on my LoginAction but the one I am using, isn't working.

I have an Entity :

```
class User implements AdvancedUserInterface {
  public function isEnabled(){}
    ...
  }
}
```

So, when, I try to connect my user i have the good message :

> user is disabled

On this action, I use an ExceptionListener like this :

```
# src/AppBundle/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php
namespace AppBundle\EventListener;


use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseForExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException;

class ExceptionListener
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onKernelException(GetResponseForExceptionEvent $event)
    {
        die('-------');

        $ex = $event->getException();
        if($ex instanceof DisabledException) {
            $url = $this->router->generate('accounts.please_activate');
            $response = new RedirectResponse($url);

            $event->setResponse($response);
        }
    }
}
```

My listener work, cause, if i do a `die` in the construct, it's ok, but, my `die` doesn't work in the function `onKernelException`

So my redirect to the specific route doesn't work...

`services.yml`

```
services:
app.exception_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\ExceptionListener
    arguments: ['@router']
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception }
```

### Question:

Why am I unable to redirect a user that is considered "disabled" to a specific route?

On a second note, is this considered good practice?

Comment: `function onKernerlException` is not called... 
so i can't `var_dump($ex)`...

It's the big problem :( and i don't know why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle the login failures with customized login handlers.

Creare a new service that implements `Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\DisabledException;

class FailLoginHandler implements AuthenticationFailureHandlerInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        if($exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            $url = $this->router->generate('accounts.please_activate');
            return new RedirectResponse($url);
        }
    }
}
```

Define a new service

```
services:
    app.login_fail:
        class:        AppBundle\Security\FailLoginHandler
        arguments:    ['@router']
```

then add the `failure_handler` option under the configuration of your firewall on **security.yml**:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        firewallname:
             failure_handler: app.login_fail
```

Comment: Just a last question about the function `onAuthenticationFailure`. If i want to connect my user and if the password is wrong, `onAuthenticationFailure` is called, good, but, $exception is not an `instanceof DisabledException` but is an `instanceOf BadCredentialException`.

It's possible to return default Response if $exception is **not** an instanceOf DisabledException ? @federico

Comment: sure, just return another response on `onAuthenticationFailure`.