# Catching DisabledException when using Custom User Checker in Symfony 4.1

Tags: php, symfony, authentication

I've implemented a Custom User Checker in Symfony following [this guide](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_checkers.html).  I need it to perform the additional check of determining if the account trying to log in is active.

Here's my User Checker code:

```
class UserChecker implements UserCheckerInterface {

    public function checkPreAuth(UserInterface $user) {
        if (!$user->getUser()->getIsActive())  {
            throw new DisabledException("Account is disabled.");
        }  else  {
            return;
        }
    }

    public function checkPostAuth(UserInterface $user) {
        return;
    }
}
```

In this case, the `$user` object that gets passed in by DI, is simply a wrapper (which implements UserInterface) of my User object.  My user object has a bool flag of `isActive`.  if `getIsActive` returns false, my condition negates that, and it should throw the `DisabledException`.

This is not the behavior I'm seeing, however.  If I log in with an active user, I can log in fine.  If I log in with a disabled user, it simply returns me back to the log in screen (no exception thrown).

If I change `DisabledException` to simply `Exception`, the exception is thrown, but I don't see a spot in my code where I can catch it so that I can show a pretty 'account is disabled' message to the user above the login screen.

I'm assuming that Symfony is catching and swallowing the `DisabledException` somewhere.

Here is my `security.yaml`:

```
security:
    providers:
        db_provider:
            id: database_user_provider
    encoders:
        App\Utility\Security\DatabaseUser: bcrypt
    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: db_provider
                login_path: login
                check_path: process_login
                default_target_path: do_some_stuff
                use_referer: true
            user_checker: App\Utility\Security\UserChecker
            anonymous: ~
            logout:
                path: logout
                target: login

    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/userRegister, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

My question is:  Where is that exception being caught / what do I need to override or implement so that I can get a message out to the user?

or

Where can I catch `Exception` to do the same thing?

Comment: There are actually multiple ways to handle this but one I can point you to is for an older version but still valid.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37718670/symfony-3-listener-on-loginaction-kernelexception?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @EresDev... yep... That worked.  Thanks!